# Xcode not recognizing my GitHub Account with an Authentication Failed error

Tags: xcode, github

I am having trouble with xCode(Version 15.0) IDE not being able to recognize my GitHub account and I can't longer add packages to my project.

Steps that I did when adding my GitHub account to Xcode:

- generated the Personal Access Token on GitHub with the required scopes: repo, user, admin:public_key, and write discussion.
- generated an RSA 4086 key on my computer and added it to my .ssh folder.
- checked my connection by using $ ssh -T git@github.com and it says I was successfully authenticated.
- Open settings in Xcode and navigate to Accounts, under Source Control Account, I clicked on the option SSH and selected the RSA key that I just generated in the previous step. Xcode prompts me with a login screen for GitHub -> Username: and Personal Access Token:. I have entered the credentials and got an error of Authentication Failed.

[Source Control Account setting in xCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiLWV.png)

Steps I have tried to resolve the issue:
-reinstalled Xcode
-regenerated my tokens/SSH keys
-removed the GitHub account and added it again in Xcode

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!